# How to use an enum in typescript as a default prop value for a react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I have an enum file `Themes.ts`

```
export enum Themes {
    DEFAULT = 'default',
    DARK = 'dark'
}
```

And I want to use that enum as a default prop in a `<Test/>` component that looks like

```
export type TestProps = {
    children: ReactChild,
    theme?: Themes,
}

export const Test = ({ children, theme = Themes.DEFAULT }: TestProps) => {
    console.log(theme)
    return (
        <div className={`${theme}`}>
            <div>
                { children }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The issue i'm seeing is that `console.log(theme)` is printing `Themes.DEFAULT` instead of `default` so the default value isn't being set properly. Is there anyway to use an enum to set this default theme value so that it will evaluate properly?

EDIT :
What ended up working was setting a const to the enum values and then passing that into the props

```
const enumValue = Themes.DEFAULT
export const Test = ({ children, theme = enumValue }: TestProps) => {
```

Answer (score 4):

Use string union types instead of enums. This way you keep the same type strength and your strings can be strings.

```
export type Themes = 'default' | 'dark';
```

Then in your component

```
export type TestProps = {
    children: ReactChild,
    theme?: Themes,
}

export const Test = ({ children, theme = 'default' }: TestProps) => {
    console.log(theme)
    return (
        <div className={`${theme}`}>
            <div>
                { children }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If you try to assign anything besides `'default'` or `'dark'`, the TS compiler will throw an error.

Comment: This was useful, but not quite what I was looking for. Wanted to avoid hardcoding strings in code

Comment: It may look like it's just hard coding a string. But it's assigning one of two possible values accepted by this type. Just like your would if using enums.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks right. I tried to reproduce it but everything works fine
https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-spence-kw3og?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: The same issue is happening with me. If I pass a ENUM as parameter, works. But, when the component uses the default value, not works, the error reported on this question happens.